# TCPDF series of errors when adding an html element to generated pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I made a pdf using TCPDF and used the `writeHTML()` function. I have one table generated from MySQL code that is displayed in my website which is also displayed on the pdf and added with a function called: `fetch_data()`. The code for the first table is as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['report'])) {
  $order_id = ($_GET['report']); 

  function fetch_data() {  
    $output = '';  
    require 'dbh.php'; 
    $order_id = ($_GET['report']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM samples_database JOIN results_database ON samples_database.sample_id = results_database.sample_id JOIN microbiology_analysis_database ON results_database.m_analysis_id = microbiology_analysis_database.id WHERE samples_database.order_id = $order_id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $order_number = $input['order_number'][0];
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {       
      $output .= ' 
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Sample ID</th>
      <th>Client ID</th>
      <th>Analysis</th>
      <th>Detected</th>  
      <th>Result</th>              
      </tr>                           
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      <tr> 
      <td><?php echo $row["env_sam_id"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["c_sam_id"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["m_analysis"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["detected"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["result"]; ?></td>                       
      </tr> 
      </tbody>
      </table>   
      ';  
    }  
    return $output;  
  } 
}
```

This generated pdf worked very nicely until an additional html table element was added under the name `fetch_data2()` which is as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['report'])) {
  $order_id = ($_GET['report']); 

  function fetch_data2() {  
    $output = '';  
    require 'dbh.php'; 
    $order_id = ($_GET['report']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_database JOIN client_database ON order_database.client_id = client_database.id  WHERE order_database.id = $order_id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $order_number = $input['order_number'];
    $time1 = $input['time1'];
    $date1 = $input['date1'];
    $client_first_name = $input['client_first_name'];
    $client_last_name = $input['client_last_name'];
    $company_name = $input['company_name'];
    $phone = $input['phone'];
    $email = $input['email'];  
    {       
      $output .= '

      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>  
      </tr>                           
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Order Number:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="date1" value="'.$order_number.'" readonly></td>                     
      </tr>  
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Order Date:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="date1" value="'.$date1.'" readonly></td>                     
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Time Placed:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="time1" value="'.$time1.'" readonly></td>                    
      </tr>   
      <tr>
      <td><strong>Client:</strong></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="client_name" value="'.$client_first_name.' '.$client_last_name.'" readonly></td>                    
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Company:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="'.$company_name.'" readonly></td>                      
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Email*:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="'.$email.'"></td>                     
      </tr>   
      <tr>
      <td><strong>Contact Number*:</strong></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="'.$phone.'"></td>                      
      </tr>  
      </tbody> 
      </table> 
      ';  
    }  
    return $output;  
  } 
}
```

Here is the code that was used to generate the PDF file:

```
if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"])) {

  $file_name = 'Microbiology_Report_'.$order_number.'.pdf';  

  require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
  require_once('tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php'); 

// create new PDF document
  $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
  $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
  $pdf->SetAuthor($_SESSION['logged_in_id']);
  $pdf->SetTitle($file_name);
  $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
  $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
  $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
  $pdf->setFooterData();
  $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
  $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
  $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
  $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
  $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
  $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
  $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
  $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
  if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
  }
  $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
  $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', true);
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $html = ''; 
  $html .= fetch_data2();    
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
  $html = '<h1 style="color:green;">Testing</h1>'; 
  $html .= '  
  <h4 align="center">Envirocare Microbiology Report</h4><br /> 
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Sample ID</th>
  <th>Client ID</th>
  <th>Analysis</th>
  <th>Detected</th>  
  <th>Result</th>              
  </tr>                           
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
  <tr> ' ;
  $html .= fetch_data();  
  $html .= ' 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  ';
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
  $html = '

  <h3>Abbreviations and remarks:</h3>
  <p>CFU: Colony Forming Units</p>
  ';
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
  ob_end_clean();
  $pdf->Output($file_name, 'I');  
}
```

I know the error has something to do with `fetch_data2()` but I have no idea what causes the error or how to format the code to make the work. The error contains various undefined index errors as well as this: `TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file`. Can anyone help to alleviate this problem?

EDIT

Here is the full error report:

```
Notice: Undefined index: startcolumn in 

C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19480

Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19481

Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19484

Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19487

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19487

Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19488

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19488

Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19543

Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19740

Notice: Undefined variable: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19741

Notice: Undefined variable: endpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19741

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18123

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18123

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18123

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18123

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18121

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18214

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18269

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18123

Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacing in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18188

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php:18188) in C:\xampp\htdocs\envirocare_lims\server\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 7625
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

Comment: Please share the full error report.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Added the report.

Comment: If you've set PHP to display errors, then this is likely preventing TCPDF from sending the required headers. But you'll probably want to clean up those warnings anyway, but I'm not seeing the variables mentioned. If you need help fixing them, then please post all relevant code.

Comment: @RoAchterberg this is the entire code I used to generate the PDF file. Only the database information is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem lies with the segment of code below. In this scenario I was trying to systematically create a table where the headings was in the first column and the database information in the second column. Turns out that the PDF generator gets confused about which is which and how to systematically append it to the PDF.

```
if (isset($_GET['report'])) {
  $order_id = ($_GET['report']); 

  function fetch_data2() {  
    $output = '';  
    require 'dbh.php'; 
    $order_id = ($_GET['report']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_database JOIN client_database ON order_database.client_id = client_database.id  WHERE order_database.id = $order_id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $order_number = $input['order_number'];
    $time1 = $input['time1'];
    $date1 = $input['date1'];
    $client_first_name = $input['client_first_name'];
    $client_last_name = $input['client_last_name'];
    $company_name = $input['company_name'];
    $phone = $input['phone'];
    $email = $input['email'];  
    {       
      $output .= '

      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>  
      </tr>                           
      </thead>
      <tbody> 
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Order Number:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="date1" value="'.$order_number.'" readonly></td>                     
      </tr>  
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Order Date:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="date1" value="'.$date1.'" readonly></td>                     
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Time Placed:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="time1" value="'.$time1.'" readonly></td>                    
      </tr>   
      <tr>
      <td><strong>Client:</strong></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="client_name" value="'.$client_first_name.' '.$client_last_name.'" readonly></td>                    
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Company:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="company_name" value="'.$company_name.'" readonly></td>                      
      </tr>   
      <tr> 
      <td><strong>Email*:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="'.$email.'"></td>                     
      </tr>   
      <tr>
      <td><strong>Contact Number*:</strong></td> 
      <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="'.$phone.'"></td>                      
      </tr>  
      </tbody> 
      </table> 
      ';  
    }  
    return $output;  
  } 
}
```

The solution was to create a traditional table where the column headings are at the top in the `<thead>` tag and the actual table rows from the database in the php code.

```
if (isset($_GET['report'])) {
  $order_id = ($_GET['report']); 

  function fetch_data2() {  
    $output = '';  
    require 'dbh.php'; 
    $order_id = ($_GET['report']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_database JOIN client_database ON order_database.client_id = client_database.id  WHERE order_database.id = $order_id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

      $output .= '
      <td>'.$row["order_number"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["date1"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["time1"].'</td> 
      <td>'.$row["client_first_name"].' '.$row["client_last_name"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["company_name"].'</td>                          
      <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>                         
      ';       
    }    
    return $output;  
  } 
}
```

Finally the `fetch_data2()` was added in the generate PDF code with the table head added as html code:

```
$pdf->AddPage();
  $html = ''; 
  $html .= '<h1 style="color:green;">Microbiology Report</h1>'; 
  $html .= '
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th><strong>Order Number:</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Order Date:</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Time Placed:</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Client:</strong></th>       
  <th><strong>Company:</strong></th> 
  <th><strong>Email*:</strong></th>
  <th><strong>Contact Number*:</strong></th>   
  </tr>                           
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
  <tr>
  ';
  $html .= fetch_data2();
  $html .= '
  </tr>  
  </tbody> 
  </table>
  ';
  $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```